# Django: Using jquery ajax call to run function when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, onclick

I am trying to run a function without refreshing the page by using the jQuery ajax() Method, but it's not working. I have very limited experience with jQuery and ajax, so would appreciate any help.

My template:

```
      <a id="add_word" href="{% url 'vocab:add-custom' word.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Add</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var wordpk = "{{word.pk}}";
  </script>
```

My view:

```
def custom_create_word(request, object):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    if request.method =="GET":
        from .forms import WordForm
        from .models import Word
        word = Word.objects.get(pk=object)
        user = request.user
        target_word = word.target_word
        source_word = word.source_word
        deck_name = "My Words"
        fluency = 0
        Word.objects.create(user=user, target_word=target_word,
                             source_word=source_word, deck_name=deck_name, fluency=fluency)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vocab:dict'))
```

My url:

```
app_name='vocab'

    path("<int:object>/",views.custom_create_word,name="add-custom"),
```

My js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#add_word").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
        url: "/vocab/"+wordpk+"/",
        success: function (result) {
          $("#add_word").html(result);
          alert("it worked");
        }});
      });
    });
```

I don't get any errors, but the function isn't run. Everything works when I do it without jquery and ajax (i.e. the function is run but the page is refreshed every time). Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Still struggling with this, can anybody help me please?**

Comment: you cannot have mutliple `ids` for same elements thats the reason its not working .

Comment: @Swati if I take 'button' out, it still doesn't work

Comment: Does your browser console showing any error? Also put an alert inside click function to see if  it's called

Comment: @Swati Do you mean I must put the alert in my view, e.g. print("Ajax function called")? I did that and nothing shows on the console, there are also no errors. So it seems the function is not being called?

Comment: Simply do `alert("something");` inside your click function and see if you clicked on your `a` tag does this shows or not

Comment: @Swati I've updated my code (realised my url was wrong). Also added the alert. I don't see anything in the console when I click. Any ideas why the function isn't being called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215553/discussion-between-swati-and-mel).